# How to transition from async.parallel & series to composable Promises?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream, promise, bluebird

I am trying to transition from async to promises and this is what I have. If the code looks contrived it's because I simplified it from what I'm working on to make it easier to grasp. I'm struggling to get the Promise.all to execute.

I commented out the async code that I want to implement in promises:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs-extra'));
var path = require('path');
var tar = require('tar-fs');

module.exports = Archive;

function Archive() {
  var self = this;
  var self.base_dir = '/bar/baz',
  var self.file1 = 'foo/file1',
  var self.file2 = 'foo/file2',
  var self.file3 = 'foo/file3',
  var self.file4 = 'foo/file4'
}

Archive.prototype.make = function(done) {
  var self = this;
  // async.series([
  //     function(next) {
  //       self._prepareFilesDir(next);
  //     },
  //     function(next) {
  //       self._copyFiles(next);
  //     },
  //     function(next) {
  //       self._writeArchive(next);
  //     }
  // ], done)
  self._prepareFilesDir().bind(self)
    .then(self._copyFiles.bind(self))
    .then(self._writeArchive.bind(self))
    .catch(function(e) {
      return done(e);
    });
};

// ********************************
// * Private functions
// ********************************

Archive.prototype._prepareFilesDir = function() {
  var self = this;
  return fs.emptyDirAsync(self.base_dir);
};

Archive.prototype._copyFiles = function() {
  var self = this;
  var sources = {
    file1: path.resolve('baz', 'file1'),
    file2: path.resolve('baz', 'file2')
    file3: path.resolve('baz', 'file3')
    file4: path.resolve('baz', 'file4')
    file5: path.resolve('baz', 'file5')
  };
  var destinations = {
    file1: path.resolve(self.base_dir, self.file1),
    file2: path.resolve(self.base_dir, self.file2),
    file3: path.resolve(self.base_dir, self.file3),
    file4: path.resolve(self.base_dir, self.file4),
    file5: path.resolve(self.base_dir, self.file5)
  };

  var filters = {
    qux: /^qux/,
    bru: /^bru/,
    blerg: /blerg$/
  };

  function copyFile1() {
    console.log('hello world');
    return fs.copyAsync(sources.file2, destinations.file1, { filter: filters.qux });
  };
  function copyFile2() {
    return fs.copyAsync(sources.file2, destinations.file2);
  };
  function copyFile3() {
    return fs.copyAsync(sources.file3, destinations.file3, { filter: filters.bru });
  };
  function copyFile4() {
    return fs.copyAsync(sources.file4, destinations.file4, { filter: filters.blerg });
  };

  return Promise.all([
      copyFile1,
      copyFile2,
      copyFile3,
      copyFile4
  ]);

  // async.parallel([
  //   copyFile1(next),
  //   copyFile2(next),
  //   copyFile3(next),
  //   copyFile4(next)
  // ], function(err) {
  //  if (err) return done(err);
  //   done(null);
  // })
};

Archive.prototype._writeArchive = function() {
  var self = this;
  var archive_dir_path = path.resolve(self.base_dir, '..');
  var tarPromise = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      tar.pack(self.files_path)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(archive_dir_path + '.tar'))
        .on('error', reject)
        .on('finish', resolve)
    });
  };

  fs.ensureDirAsync(archive_dir_path)
    .then(tarPromise);
};
```

I must be doing something wrong because the 'hello world' is never printed. I think the stream is promisified correctly but I'm not so sure either. I based my conversion on the promise-nuggets.github.io snippets.

How do I have to do the `Promise.all`? I'd like to keep separate functions as I think it helps understanding the code better.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

the mistakes that I found:

- in `make` method, done would be called only in case of error, suggestion remove `done` callback, just return promise
- again in `make`, you are doing `_prepareFilesDir().bind(self)`, for staters `bind` at that point is redundant, it should have been `call/apply` at that point.
- in `_writeArchive`, you need to return promise, else it ll return undefined and assume that the async function is finished.

  updated code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsn8mrf2/)

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code with your suggestions, however:


1. When is an error handled at all if I remove the catch in `make`?


2. The `console.log('hello world');` still doesn't seem to be run because it isn't printed

Comment: @springloaded now `make` would return a promise,  you can chain a `catch` to it to see errors, where are trying console.log ?

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues which @mido22 fixed. There is one more issue though, in Pormise.all(), the functions shouldn't be passed as references but rather executed.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs-extra'));
var path = require('path');
var tar = require('tar-fs');

module.exports = Archive;

function Archive() {
  var self = this;
  var self.base_dir = '/bar/baz',
  var self.file1 = 'foo/file1',
  var self.file2 = 'foo/file2',
  var self.file3 = 'foo/file3',
  var self.file4 = 'foo/file4'
}

Archive.prototype.make = function() { // CHANGED
  var self = this;
  // async.series([
  //     function(next) {
  //       self._prepareFilesDir(next);
  //     },
  //     function(next) {
  //       self._copyFiles(next);
  //     },
  //     function(next) {
  //       self._writeArchive(next);
  //     }
  // ], done)
  return self._prepareFilesDir() // CHANGED
    .then(self._copyFiles.bind(self))
    .then(self._writeArchive.bind(self)); // CHANGED
};

// ********************************
// * Private functions
// ********************************

Archive.prototype._prepareFilesDir = function() {
  var self = this;
  return fs.emptyDirAsync(self.base_dir);
};

Archive.prototype._copyFiles = function() {
  var self = this;
  var sources = {
    file1: path.resolve('baz', 'file1'),
    file2: path.resolve('baz', 'file2')
    file3: path.resolve('baz', 'file3')
    file4: path.resolve('baz', 'file4')
    file5: path.resolve('baz', 'file5')
  };
  var destinations = {
    file1: path.resolve(self.base_dir, self.file1),
    file2: path.resolve(self.base_dir, self.file2),
    file3: path.resolve(self.base_dir, self.file3),
    file4: path.resolve(self.base_dir, self.file4),
    file5: path.resolve(self.base_dir, self.file5)
  };

  var filters = {
    qux: /^qux/,
    bru: /^bru/,
    blerg: /blerg$/
  };

  function copyFile1() {
    console.log('hello world');
    return fs.copyAsync(sources.file2, destinations.file1, { filter: filters.qux });
  };
  function copyFile2() {
    return fs.copyAsync(sources.file2, destinations.file2);
  };
  function copyFile3() {
    return fs.copyAsync(sources.file3, destinations.file3, { filter: filters.bru });
  };
  function copyFile4() {
    return fs.copyAsync(sources.file4, destinations.file4, { filter: filters.blerg });
  };

  return Promise.all([
      copyFile1(), // execute functions
      copyFile2(), // idem
      copyFile3(), // idem
      copyFile4()  // idem
  ]);

  // async.parallel([
  //   copyFile1(next),
  //   copyFile2(next),
  //   copyFile3(next),
  //   copyFile4(next)
  // ], function(err) {
  //  if (err) return done(err);
  //   done(null);
  // })
};

Archive.prototype._writeArchive = function() {
  var self = this;
  var archive_dir_path = path.resolve(self.base_dir, '..');
  var tarPromise = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      tar.pack(self.files_path)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(archive_dir_path + '.tar'))
        .on('error', reject)
        .on('finish', resolve)
    });
  };

  return fs.ensureDirAsync(archive_dir_path)
    .then(tarPromise);  // CHANGED, 
};
```